LinkedIn and Twitter Not Scraping My Next.js Page
I'm facing a bit of a challenge with getting LinkedIn and Twitter to properly scrape and preview one of my pages built with Next.js. Here’s what’s happening:
The Issue:

LinkedIn Post Inspector: When I try to scrape the page with LinkedIn’s Post Inspector, I get the following error:
Ingestion feedback
Error: We did not scrape the content because its size was larger than our threshold. Maximum size for this input stream is 3145728 bytes.

This suggests that the page exceeds LinkedIn's size limit of around 3 MB, making it impossible for them to scrape the content or generate a preview.

Twitter: On Twitter, the preview image isn’t showing up at all. I’ve checked the Open Graph and Twitter card tags, and everything seems correct, but Twitter still doesn't display the image.


What I Need Help With:

Handling Size Limits: Does anyone know effective strategies for dealing with content size limits when scraping with LinkedIn? How can I ensure that the page gets scraped and a preview is generated even if the page is large?

Twitter Image Preview Issues: Why might Twitter not be displaying the preview image even when the correct twitter:image tag is present? Are there known issues or tricks to ensure the image appears?

Fallback Solutions: If reducing the page size isn’t an option, are there any alternative solutions or workarounds? For example, is it possible to force LinkedIn or Twitter to scrape a specific URL for the image, even if the page itself is large?

General Best Practices: What are the best practices for ensuring social media platforms can properly scrape and generate previews for Next.js pages? Are there any tools or plugins that could help with this?


I’d really appreciate any insights or advice you might have. This issue is causing some frustration, and any help would be valuable. Thanks in advance!

I resolved this issue.
I created a new simple page to direct to target page, this new page can be passed from LinkedIn Post Inspector.
This is a workaround.
